# WHERE Clause for SOQL Query for a date and a case origin type in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

my objective is to pull a list of cases within Salesforce Service Cloud using SOQL that have happened within this year and are specifically email-to-case.

If I try this: `SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate > 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z AND Origin = 'Email'`
it says "no records returned".

However, if I do

`SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE (CreatedDate > 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z)`

or

`SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'Email'`

it returns records. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have email ones this year? Your query looks fine. I just tried `SELECT CreatedDate,Origin FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate > 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z AND Origin = 'Web'` in a scratch org and it worked fine (there were no 'Email' cases in my DE)

Comment: I think your query seems ok. Are you sure your query `SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'Email'` returns any record? I got record using the query `SELECT CreatedDate,Origin FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate > 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z AND Origin = 'Phone'` in my DE org

Comment: I am sure I have emails from this year, because I am able to pull them using  `SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'Email'`

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the result of your query, but please also use the Origin field (SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate, Origin FROM Case WHERE (CreatedDate > 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z)).
I had a situation once where the case trigger overwrote a value. I guess this happened here too and your Case Origin for this year is no longer email.

Comment: @q-jack I think I may have figured it out! since we have so many email queues, I used the LIKE function with a wildcard. The query I used was `SELECT CaseNumber, CreatedDate, ClosedDate, Origin FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate > 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z AND Origin LIKE 'Email%'`